# JavaScript: catching URI change

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, uri, jquery-events

I have a site where I'm using hash based parameters, eg.

```
http://url.of.site/#param1=123
```

**What I want**

When the user manually changes the URI to eg.

```
http://url.of.site/#param1=789
```

When the user enters this URI, the event is caught by the JavaScript, and the appropriate functions are called. Basically, what I'm wondering about is; is there an event listener for this? Or would I have to periodically check the URI to see if it has been changed?

I'm already using the current jQuery API, if that helps.

Comment: Duplicate of [On - window.location.hash - change?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)