# Does onHashChange work in Safari?

Tags: javascript, hash, safari, hashchange

Does `onHashChange` or `hashChange` work in Safari? I tested it with Safari 4.0.4 on Windows 7 and it doesn't work for me.

If it doesn't work, is there any solution to track if the `hash` has changed?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change there you'll find your solution. Answer to question, does it work in Safari? - No.

Comment: Oh, _please_. Try "F*cking IE" on for size

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Safari 4.0.4` it's not working yet but in the latest one works fine. And I didn't find any acceptable solutions to track if the hash has changed for those browsers which don't support `onHashChange`.

Comment: if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    alert("The browser supports the hashchange event!");
}

Answer (score 1):

In our app we poll to check for changes:

```
$b.hashCheck = setInterval(
    function(){
        if ( window.location.hash !== $b.C.current_hash){
            $b.C.current_hash = window.location.hash;

            //call the on change action here

        }
    },$b.C.hashCheckDelay
);
```

$b is the global object we use for our namespace and `hashCheckDelay` was empirically set at 120ms.
While it looks a bit sad to do this kind of process, there isn't any performance issue on any browser we tested.

Comment: thanks for your answer, this could be a solution to track if the hash has changed in the browsers who don't support `onHashChange` however this is not a good solution because with a lots of queries requires too much performance.

Comment: I use it in our app, but a single function checks and dispatch the message to the relevant object. Without problems of performance.