# Detect youtube video switching in Firefox

Tags: firefox, youtube, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

I'm developing an extension that needs to be triggered when a user switched videos on youtube.

I've tried to listen to load or pageshow but they are not triggered when a user is watching a video and clicks another one

```
var tabs = require("sdk/tabs");

tabs.on('pageshow', function(tab) {
    //do something
});
```

Comment: I don't think youtube uses pageshow, here is an addon that watches page switching: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/listenonrepeat/ i would look into how this guy does it. I also did it in the past but i was experimenting with some complex methods (using nsIWebProgressListener here: https://github.com/Noitidart/Listen-on-Repeat-Youtube-Video-Repeater )

Comment: I think the simplest solution was to attach mutation observer to the the red loading bar on page load of youtube, as page loads dont trigger after that. From here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18398921/1828637

Comment: This solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30464941/detect-tab-url-change-inside-firefox-add-on

works for youtube url changes

Comment: Thanks for sharing Tiago! He put the solution all nice and neat, you can see in here I have onLocationChange too haha but mine had lots of code around it so it looked scary.

Answer (score 0):

Use a history pushstate listener if you want this to work with any modern webapp that changes the URL without refreshing the page. See [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26068962/1720014)