# In Chrome Extension，How to prevent page redirect when <a> tag is clicked

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I have a chrome extension.

What I want to is :

When an `<a>` tag is clicked in a page (named A) , I use `chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest` to block the request.

The question is:

I tried both `{redirectUrl: 'javascript:'}` and `{cancel: true}`,  but the page A still redirect.

How can I prevent the redirect in chrome extension.

manifest.json:

```
{
  "background": {
    "page": "background.html"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "img/19.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "test"
  },
  "icons": {
    "128": "img/128.png",
    "48": "img/48.png"
  },
  "is_account_related": false,
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "minimum_chrome_version": "38.0.0.0",
  "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "notifications", "tabs", "storage", "cookies", "http://*/*", "https://*/*", "*://*/*"],
  "homepage_url": "xxxx",
  "name": "test",
  "description": "test",
  "version": "10.3.6",
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' 'unsafe-eval' xxx 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'",
  "key": "xxx"
}
```

background.html

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
        function (details) {
            console.log('========start============');
            console.log('block', details, details.url);
            console.log('========end============');
            // return { redirectUrl: 'javascript:' };
            return { cancel: true };
        },
        { urls: ["*://developer.mozilla.org/*"] },
        ['blocking']
    );
```

In the background.html, the log is correct. But the page still navigate

=== update

I find that the page use `history` API to navigate. So is there any way to prevent `history` api, like `history.push`, `history.replace` ?

Comment: 1) Show your code and manifest.json, it may have a mistake. 2) The page may have its own click listener and navigate to the new URL by manipulating `location` object which you can inspect in devtools (element panel, event listeners subpanel). The latter can be blocked by a content script using the standard event methods like stopPropagation().

Comment: Yeah, I find that the page has its own click listener. But I prefer not to inject javascript to the page. Is there any way else to block the request of navigating ?

Comment: Well, there's probably a mistake in your code/manifest after all. Because webRequest should be able to block any page-initiated navigation regardless of its method.

Comment: Regarding your new edit: a history navigation isn't a real navigation so to block it you'll have to override pushState in page context ([partial example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9651737)).

Comment: Ok. get it . Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You could also `return false;` every time `<a>` clicked like this:

```
for(elem of  document.getElementsByTagName("a")){
    elem.onclick = () => false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have appropriate permissions in your manifest, as it is mentioned in the docs

> As this function uses a blocking event handler, it requires the "webRequest" as well as the "webRequestBlocking" permission in the manifest file.

Also you can try something like

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
    function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
     {urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
     ["blocking"]);
```