# How to detect when history.pushState and history.replaceState are used?

Tags: javascript, html, browser-history, pushstate

Is there some event I can subscribe to when the history state is modified? How?

Answer (score 47):

I used to use this to also be notified of when `pushState` and `replaceState` are called:

```
// Add this:
var _wr = function(type) {
    var orig = history[type];
    return function() {
        var rv = orig.apply(this, arguments);
        var e = new Event(type);
        e.arguments = arguments;
        window.dispatchEvent(e);
        return rv;
    };
};
history.pushState = _wr('pushState'), history.replaceState = _wr('replaceState');

// Use it like this:
window.addEventListener('replaceState', function(e) {
    console.warn('THEY DID IT AGAIN!');
});
```

It's usually overkill though. And it might not work in all browsers. (I only care about my version of my browser.)

**NB.** It also doesn't work in Google Chrome extension content scripts, because it's not allowed to alter the site's JS environment. You can work around that by inserting a `<script>` with said code, but that's even more overkill.

Comment: In my case Browser complaint about missing `arguments` in this override... just changed first returned function to `return function(...arguments) {`