# WebKit on OS X: How to detect a JS call to pushState() in a WebView?

Tags: javascript, objective-c, macos, cocoa, webkit

Assume I have a Mac OS X application which links to WebKit and uses a WebView to display web content.

If the JavaScript in this webview calls the `window.history.pushState()` method, how do I detect this in Objective-C?

Ideally, I'm looking for something like an ObjC delegate callback which informs my application: **"pushState() was called with these parameters: XXX".**

---

*Note*: I am really looking for a solution in ObjC. Assume it is not acceptable for me to muck around with the JS on the page and replace/swizzle the `pushState()` method in JS.

Comment: Just so I understand, is it acceptable to muck around with the pushState method from *ObjC*? You can use the WebView API to provide your own custom pushState from ObjC in that case.

Comment: I'll say that's not acceptable. Since this is a method of `window.history`, that would mean I would have to significantly alter WebKit internals. My app only links to WebKit. Bundling a custom version of WebKit for this feature alone is not acceptable in this case.

Comment: Alternatively, I suppose I could provide a replacement implementation of `window.history` without bundling a custom WebKit in my app. But again, let's assume that's unacceptable, as that strikes me as a bad idea/not worth the effort for this feature.

Comment: I think you can grab the history webScriptObject in ObjC and just change pushState alone using something like [historyObject setValue:customCallable forKey:@"pushState"].

Comment: However I agree there's probably a way to do it without all that at all -- I would just look at the pushState implementation and see what that is calling internally. I would suspect it does a URL request or something. Specifically webView:decidePolicyForNavigationAction:request:frame:decisionListener: may be called

Comment: I see. Good point. I was hoping there was some API for this that I just couldn't find, but I see your idea may be the best way.

Comment: and Calling Objective-C Methods From JavaScript ? here :https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/appleapplications/Conceptual/SafariJSProgTopics/Tasks/ObjCFromJavaScript.html

Comment: @divol As stated, any solution involving mucking with the JavaScript directly is not acceptable.

Comment: so it's Schrödinger's cat  !!! :D

Comment: what about SafariBeforeNavigateEvent SafariNavigateEvent ? okay it's for extensions ....

Comment: window.onpopstate is interesting, but not for objective-c ...  MortBleue !

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129386/how-to-dected-when-history-pushstate-and-history-replacestate-are-used

and http://code.google.com/p/html5-history/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found these private APIs in the WebKit source tree. This is exactly what I'm looking for, except that they are private, which may present problems for my particular use case.

```
@interface NSObject (WebFrameLoadDelegatePrivate)
...
- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didPushStateWithinPageForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame ;
- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didReplaceStateWithinPageForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;
- (void)webView:(WebView *)wv didPopStateWithinPageForFrame:(WebFrame *)frame;
@end
```

Comment: Generally, Apple seems to ignore the use of private APIs in WebKit, at least in my experience. Perhaps because the source is open?