# Prevent hash navigation in browser

Tags: javascript, single-page-application, browser-history

I'm implementing router for navigating in single-page application (something like Angular's `ui-router`). Routing will be done by changing browser location's hash.

It should be impossible to navigate to an undeclared route. So if I've declared only `#/foo` route, and currently I'm on `#/foo` and trying to change hash to `#/bar`, browser should revert hash to `#/foo`.

However, after that `#/bar` will remain in browser's history. The question is: how to completely prevent history changing on hash navigation?

I've tried

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    return false;
})
```

but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This has already been answered. You can use onpopstate event to detect when the user hits forward/back but you will need to wrap the pushState and replaceState methods to detect when they are used. Examples are shown here: [How to detect when history.pushState and history.replaceState are used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5129386/how-to-detect-when-history-pushstate-and-history-replacestate-are-used)