# Get tab URL from page action (WebExtensions, Android)

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome-extension, tabs, firefox-addon-webextensions

I would like to get the URL of the current tab within a page action popup.
At first it seems obvious: Just use the [tabs](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#tabs) API. But that doesn't seem to be available on Android if I deciphering the docs correctly. So I kept looking for something else and found the [onClicked](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/PageAction/onClicked#addListener_syntax) event of the pageAction API.

The [pageAction API](http://arewewebextensionsyet.com/#pageAction) seems to be listed as compatible with Android and the onClicked event is marked as supported. So that implies that it would actually return a tabs.Tab object. But does it really? Has anyone tried it?

What is the best way to retrieve the URL? I know I could just use a content script and let that run in every single tab and create a long lived messaging connection to send the URL to the page action popup whenever it is requested. But that would be very inefficient and make the code insanely complicated compared to how easy it would be using the tabs API.

Is there anything else I could do?

Comment: It sounds like you are already writing code which has basically everything needed to test if the `pageAction.onClicked` event provides a `tab.Tabs` object. Why are you asking if anyone has tried it instead of trying it yourself?

Comment: Because I don't have an Android phone at the moment.

Answer (score 12):

## Current (Firefox 54 and later)

As of Firefox 54, the [`tabs` API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs) is available in Firefox for Android. This means you can use the normal methods available to desktop Firefox.  Specifically, [`chrome.tabs.query()` or `browser.tabs.query()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query). However, you will need the `activeTab` and/or `tabs` [`permissions`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json/permissions) in your [*manifest.json*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/manifest.json).

`chrome.tabs.query`:

```
chrome.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true},function(tabs){
    //'tabs' will be an array with only one element: an Object describing the active tab
    //  in the current window.
    var currentTabUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

`browser.tabs.query`:

```
browser.tabs.query({active:true,currentWindow:true}).then(function(tabs){
    //'tabs' will be an array with only one element: an Object describing the active tab
    //  in the current window.
    var currentTabUrl = tabs[0].url;
});
```

## Prior to Firefox 54

### If you have defined a page/browser action popup

If you have defined a popup for your page/browser action, then the `onClicked` event does not fire. Your popup is not passed any information when it is created/shown. Thus, you will not receive a [`tabs.Tab`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/Tab) object. The normal way to obtain tab information is from [`tabs.query`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs/query), which, as you have already determined, is not (yet) available in Firefox for Android.

The [APIs available to Firefox on Android](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs) are quite limited.  For what you are wanting to do, using [`webNavigation`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation) events to keep a record of each tab's frame 0 URL would be more efficient than a content script in every page. You could use the [`webNavigation.onCommitted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCommitted) or [`webNavigation.onCompleted`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/onCompleted) events depending on your needs. You will need to *assume* that the active tab of the current window is the one which most recently had a `webNavigation` event, or perhaps you could also monitor [`webRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webRequest) events. However, any way that you do it, which tab you *assume* to be the current tab will just be an assumption, and *will* be inaccurate under some circumstances.

#### A more accurate URL (and active tab determination) requires using a content script

If the page that is being visited changes the tab's URL through some method that does not trigger navigation, using `webNavigation` events will not give you the updated URL. As you have identified, without the `tabs` API, the only way to be certain you have the actual current URL for the tab, when you define an actual page/browser action popup (and thus don't get a `tabs.Tab` object), is to inject a content script into every page. You will either need the content scripts to continuously update the URLs, or be listening with [`storage.onChanged`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/storage/onChanged) for a request for that information from your background/popup script. Communication *from* the background/popup scripts *to* content scripts must be accomplished through the `storage` API due to not having the `tabs` API (i.e. no [`tabs.sendMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/tabs)).

### Using page/browser action `onClicked`

An alternative, which I have not tried on Firefox on Android, would be to not define an actual page/browser action popup. If you don't define an actual popup, you receive the `onClicked` event (getting the `tabs.Tab` Object with both the active tab's ID and the URL) and then can [open a pseudo-popup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40282137/how-to-create-a-global-hotkey-for-opening-the-browseraction-popup-in-firefox/40296092#40296092)<sup>1</sup>.

---

<sub>1. The implementation of opening a a pseudo-popup in my linked answer uses the [`tabs`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs#tabs) and [`windows`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Browser_support_for_JavaScript_APIs#windows) APIs which are both currently unavailable for Firefox for Android. It could be re-written to use the above mentioned `webNavigation` listener to track tab URLs and `window.open()` to open the window used for the pseudo-popup. Again, I have not tested this with Firefox on Android to determine that it actually works.</sub>

Comment: When does the webNavigation event get fired though in Firefox? Would I actually be able to find out whenever the URL in the navigation bar changes? The [TransitionQualifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/webNavigation/TransitionQualifier) don't seem to be fully implemented. I'm especially worried about sites like YouTube which use some black magic to change the URL [and no one seems to understand how they do it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41773388/what-do-websites-like-youtube-use-to-change-the-url-without-fireing-popstate-or).

Comment: Note that Android support for tabs apis is close to landing and should be in Firefox 54.  See https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1260548

Answer (score 0):

You can get it this way with webextensions. Take into account that if you want to debug a popup, you have to "prevent popups to be closed" (4-squares icon at the top-right of the browser's toolbox)

```
var activeTabPromise = browser.tabs.query({active: true, currentWindow: true});
      activeTabPromise.then((tabs) => {

          console.log(tabs[0].url);
      });
```

I hope this will help you,