# Browser extension API active tab always returns the same tab

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to use the browser APIs to get the current url, so that I can decide create a context menu if it's a certain URL.

I've seen a [similar question on here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41940986/get-tab-url-from-page-action-webextensions-android) but it doesn't seem to do what I'm expecting.

When using the `tabs.query` method, it always logs the same tab into the console (I have permissions added).

```
browser.tabs.query({currentWindow: true, active: true})
.then(tabs => {
    let tab = tabs[0];
    console.log(tab);
})
.catch(err => {
    console.error(err);
});
```

I would expect this to log a different tab to the console as I move from one tab to the next. Am I missing something?

Comment: That looks right. This code's in a background script?

Comment: Yeah in a background scripts. When I 'reload' the manifest in Firefox it will log the 'about:debugging' tab to the console. But when switching to any other tab, nothing gets logged.