# Change style on hash change

Tags: javascript

I am looking for a way to change part of style by changing the hash. Let me explain by an example:

1. The current URL is:
   `example.com/drinks/?all-drinks=drinks`
2. Then I click on the checkbox and the URL will change to :
   `example.com/drinks/?all-drinks=drinks&drinks=spirits-drinks`

I want to change `style` of a class.

I try the following code but it is not working:

```
<script>
$( window ).on( 'hashchange', function( e ) {
    console.log( 'hash changed' );
} );
</script>
```

In fact, every time the hash changes nothing appears in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Window: `hashchange` event <sup>[[docs]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/hashchange_event)</sup>

> The hashchange event is fired when the **fragment identifier of the URL** has changed (the part of the URL beginning with and following the `#` symbol).

Sine you're trying to detect `?all-drinks=drinks` to `?all-drinks=drinks&drinks=spirits-drinks` this is **not** covered in `hashchange`

---

1. You could extend `locationchange` as [@aljgom](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3577695/aljgom) explains here: [in his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52809105/5625547).

   <sup>Example [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pau123ct/3/)</sup>
2. Or the [`onpopstate`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/popstate) event, explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41825103/5625547)
3. Or some *monkey patching* to 'fake' some sort of `onpushstate` explained [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10419898/is-there-a-callback-for-history-pushstate/10419974#10419974)

Comment: I try `<script>window.addEventListener('locationchange', function(){
    console.log('location changed!');
})</script>` in `<body>` , but in console nothing appear.

Comment: Please Read the complete answer, you'll need to extend some, it's wel explained in the answer.

Comment: @M.SallarRabiei I've added a JSFiddle link with a small example.

Comment: I appreciate your kindness @0stone0 , in the `JsFiddle` you add, it always change the URL, but I want to `check the current URL` in any changes by `ajax`, and if URL is equal to `X` it contains a specific style, and if URL is equal to `Y` contain the specific style.

Comment: Does [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Lb7kctud/3/) help? Otherwise, please elaborate the question.

Comment: Many thanks, I am a little bit confused, as I mentioned in question, I just want to check URL live, and if URL equals `https://example.com/drinks/?all-drinks=drinks` change color, and if URL equal  `https://example.com/drinks/?all-drinks=drinks&drinks=spirits-drinks` use another color for the element. In the JSFiddle it generates URL, and I do not completely understand how to use that.

Comment: Thanks, the first link you provide inspire me and I finally find a way. many thank @0stone0

Answer (score 1):

### CSS Solution

Depending on your environment, you may just want something like this...

```css
section[data-page] {
  min-height: 100vh;
}

section[data-page]:not(:target) {
  display: none;
}

section[data-page]:target {
  display: block;
}

section[data-page][id="/home"] {  /* oneoff example */
  background-color: firebrick;
}
```

```html
...
<body>
  <section id="/home">
    Home Page
  </section>
  <section id="/about">
    About Page
  </section>
  <section id="/about/consulting">
    Consulting Page
  </section>
  ...
</body>
...
```

When the location's hash value is, say, `#/about` the browser will scroll to the first element in the DOM whose `id === location.hash.replace('#', '')` (omits the `#`). This is how Single Page Applications *originally* came to being. That is, they used "*Internal Bookmarking*" -- literally within a single page -- and just scrolled the user around to different "targets". In fact, every page has an automatic/inherent Internal Bookmark called `top`. That is why you can always write `{url}#top` in the URL Bar to jump directly to the top of any page. Luckily, CSS now provides us with *Smooth Scrolling* that you'll likely want to implement as well.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_selectors/Using_the_:target_pseudo-class_in_selectors