# $(window).on('hashchange') Not firing when I change the hash with Jquery programmatically?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two Jquery functions one is

```
$('.navbar-nav').on('click', 'a', function (event) {
    event.preventDefault(); //prevents quick jumps.
    var href = $.attr(this, 'href');
    href = href.replace(/^\//, '');
    if (href != '#') {
        if ($(href).length) {
            var g = $(href).offset().top - h;
            $bod.animate({
                scrollTop: g - 5
            }, 1000,
            function () { //change hash here
                if (history.pushState) {
                    history.pushState(null, null, href);
                }
                else {
                    window.location.hash = href;
                }
            });
        }
    };
    var g = $(window).width();
    if (g <= 768) {
        $(".navbar-toggle").click();
    }
});
```

And the second function is

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    alert(location.hash);
});
```

The hash change event does not alert. I am guessing that i might not be using `event.preventdefault()` properly. I am new to Jquery and cannot understand why `hashchange` is not triggered. Any ideas?

**Edit:** this code is wrapped in `$(document).ready()` & `var $bod = $('html,body');` can this be the reason?
**Edit:** The console does not present any Jquery errors.

Comment: Maybe you need ensure that DOM is ready $(function() { $(window).on('hashchange', ... });

Comment: Should just work. What is `$bod`? body?

Comment: where did you trigger the event?

Comment: Its a constant for var $bod = $('html,body');

Comment: @Larry After the animation the function changes the hash.

Comment: Might be because `hashchange` event doesn't listen to `history.pushState`

Comment: @user2175422 if you know exactly where you want the event to be triggered why not fire it manually by putting $(window).trigger('hashchange') after the animation? or you can create a custom event that you have more control over it

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate

Comment: @Larry I tried your solution by putting the code after `history.pushstate()` but now it is triggered twice.

Comment: @user2175422 did you put it under history.pushState(null, null, href);?

Comment: @Larry yes exactly after it in the `if` condition since putvande's comment is right.

Comment: @user2175422 could you please put it under the animation? $bod.animate({
                    scrollTop: g - 5
                }, 1000,
                function () { //change hash here
                    if (history.pushState) {
                        history.pushState(null, null, href);
                    }
                    else {
                        window.location.hash = href;
                    }
                });

Comment: @Larry Thanks for the reply. But I just changed the complete function and added animation on hash change cause that was my original plan.

Comment: I found the answer to this question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know 'hashchange' is not a native jQuery event. It doesn't work for me either with jQuery. Just using regular JS works fine however, ie:

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {
    // DO STUFF
}, false);
```

And window.attachEvent... for older versions of IE