# How to execute a content script every time a page loads?

Tags: javascript, github, google-chrome-extension, content-script, document-ready

I'm writing a Chrome extension that provides a content script to any page on GitHub (i.e. any URL matching `https://github.com/*`).

I'm simply trying to log something to the console each time a page on GitHub loads, like so:

```
window.onload = function() {
  console.log("LOAD");
};
```

This listener function is executed the very first time a GitHub page is loaded, but if the user navigates to other pages on GitHub from there (by clicking on links or through other means), it doesn't fire. Why? :(

Steps to reproduce:

1. Open any repository's page on GitHub ([example](https://github.com/gulpjs/plugins)). You should see the message logged to the console.
2. Click on any link on that page. When the new page is loaded, no message is logged. :(

How do I solve this?

Answer (score 2):

It seems that GitHub uses AJAX (along with `history.pushState`) to load some parts of the site, so `onload` will fire only when the page truly loads, but not when content is loaded via AJAX.

Since GitHub uses `pushState` to change the URL when AJAX content is done loading, you can detect when that happens, and execute your code.
There isn't actually a native event right now that fires when `pushState` is used, but there's this [little hack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate):

```
(function(history){
    var pushState = history.pushState;
    history.pushState = function(state) {
        if (typeof history.onpushstate == "function") {
            history.onpushstate({state: state});
        }
        return pushState.apply(history, arguments);
    }
})(window.history);
```

So, run that, and then, instead of `window.onload`, you can do:

```
history.onpushstate = function () {
    console.log("LOAD");
};
```

Not ALL of GitHub page's load this way (`AJAX + pushState`), so you'd have to use both, `window.onload` and `history.onpushstate`.

Also, you should use `window.addEventListener('load', fn);` instead of `window.onload`, since you don't know if GitHub's code could be overwriting `window.onload`.

Comment: This answer requires special adaptation to Chrome Extension case. Since a content script [executes in a separate context](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#execution-environment), modifying the `pushState` will not affect the page's copy of it. You need to [inject the above code in the page's context](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script).