# Listening to URL change on Twitch.tv

Tags: javascript

When you browse all games on Twitch and you click on a game, it gets the content dynamically without reloading the page. The url also changes from `https://www.twitch.tv/directory` to `https://www.twitch.tv/directory/game/GameNameHere`. How can I listen to this url change?

I tried using `window.onpopstate` in the following code (in a TamperMonkey script) but the event doesn't fire.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log("Running"); // works

    window.onpopstate = function(e) {
        console.log("onpopstate triggered");
    };
});
```

**Edit**: Upon further investigation, it seems that for TamperMonkey, I had to use `unsafeWindow` instead of `window` to get `onpopstate` to work. However, `onpopstate` only works for when the browser goes back or forward. Please refer to the accepted answer for the other cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See here:
[How to get notified about changes of the history via history.pushState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate)

Basically, you'll want to intercept calls to pushState and replaceState.  If you can't do that, you can (ugly) use a setInterval to monitor the URL for changes.