# Detect this event on Chrome: change of URL change without reloading

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

I have a website that changes the URL without reloading with the following command on Chrome:

```
window.history.pushState(“object or string”, “Title”, “/new-url”);
```

Is there a way to detect such an event from Javascript?
I tried this, but it doesn't work:

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
    alert("CHANGED!!");
});
```

Comment: Why don't you trigger your own custom event?

Comment: The website is not really mine, is SLACK. And I am just writing a Chrome Extension...

Comment: I mean if it's your own code that calls `pushState`, then just after that, trigger any custom event (or popstate one e.g), see [trigger()](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: Unfortunately that is not my own code. My Chrome extension is the one that needs to detect the URL change. Any possibility to do this even if it requires timers and loops?

Comment: You can just re-define the `history.pushState` function, adding your custom event logic, and then `apply` the original function. See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4585031/1814840. You just need to inject it into the page on load using a content script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Would work only for **Chrome Extensions**:

Given:

```
var stateObj = { foo: "bar" };
history.pushState(stateObj, "page 2", "yourwebsite.com/page2");
```

you can detect it with this:

```
chrome.webNavigation.onHistoryStateUpdated.addListener(function(e) {
    console.log(e);
}, {url: [{hostEquals: 'yourwebsite.com'}]});
```