# clearinterval() outside of jquery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, setinterval

I create plugin something like this

**timer plugin**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.timer = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            seconds: 60
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var seconds = options.seconds;
            var $this = $(this);

            var timerIntval;

            var Timer =  {
                setTimer : function() {
                    clearInterval(timerIntval);
                    if(seconds <= 0) {
                        alert("timeout");
                    }else {
                        timerIntval = setInterval(function(){
                            return Timer.getTimer();
                        }, 1000);
                    }
                },
                getTimer : function () {
                    if (seconds <= 0) {
                        $this.html("0");
                    } else {
                        seconds--;
                        $this.html(seconds);
                    }
                }
            }

            Timer.setTimer();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

and I call the plugin like this.

```
$(".myTimer").timer({
    seconds : 100
});
```

i called the plugin at `timerpage.php`. When i changed the page to `xxx.php` by clicking another menu, the timer interval is still running and i need to the clear the timer interval.

i created a webpage using jquery ajax load. so my page was not refreshing when i change to another menu.

my question is, how to clear the timer interval or destroy the plugin when i click another menu?

Comment: If the JS doesn’t reset when changing the page URL, then it seems you’re using the History API (`pushState`). Then you can use the `popstate`, `pagehide` or `pageshow` event to detect this.

Comment: the js doesn't reset the url, it just changed the div content only when changing page.. could you be more spesific? @Xufox

Comment: so, whenever you are changing the div content; i will suggest you to clear the previously created interval.

Comment: so how to clear the created interval? @vijayP

Comment: ok..let me add answer for this. Give me some time.

Comment: @WilliamChandra _“[T]he [JS] doesn't reset the [URL]”_… that’s not what I said. When you change the URL (the location) of a page (by hand, via JS, with whatever technology), the JavaScript itself should reset. This includes any timeouts. You said _“When [I] changed the page to `xxx.php` by clicking another menu”_, so I assume you actually navigate to a completely distinct document, thus changing the location. This should automatically reset any timeouts, unless you use the History API or it’s not actually `timerpage.php` vs. `xxx.php` but actually `samepage.php#menuA` vs. `samepage.php#menuB`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with following modifications:

**timer plugin:**

```
(function($) {

    $.fn.timer = function(options) {

        var defaults = {
            seconds: 60
        };

        var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

        return this.each(function() {
            var seconds = options.seconds;
            var $this = $(this);

            var timerIntval;

            var Timer =  {
                setTimer : function() {
                    clearInterval(timerIntval);
                    if(seconds <= 0) {
                        alert("timeout");
                    }else {
                        timerIntval = setInterval(function(){
                            return Timer.setTimer();
                        }, 1000);

                        $this.data("timerIntvalReference", timerIntval); //saving the timer reference for future use
                    }
                },
                getTimer : function () {
                    if (seconds <= 0) {
                        $this.html("0");
                    } else {
                        seconds--;
                        $this.html(seconds);
                    }
                }
            }

            Timer.setTimer();
        });
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Now in some other JS code which is going to change the `div` content

```
var intervalRef = $(".myTimer").data("timerIntvalReference"); //grab the interval reference
clearInterval(intervalRef); //clear the old interval reference

//code to change the div content on menu change
```

For clearing timer associated with multiple DOM element, you may check below code:

```
//iterate ovel all timer element:
$("h3[class^=timer]").each(function(){
    var intervalRef = $(this).data("timerIntvalReference"); //grab the interval reference
    clearInterval(intervalRef);
});
```

Hope this will give an idea to deal with this situation.

Comment: it works for this case, but i have so many classes in my case.. `<h3 class="timerA"></h3><h3 class="timerB">` etc. so how can i call the element? i do something like this, but its not working. `$("h3[class^=timer]").data("timerIntvalReference")`

Comment: `$("h3[class^=timer]")` will return you a list of object. To clear interval associated with them; you will have iterate over them as shown in updated answer.

Comment: so i must declare it one by one?

Comment: no..thats not mandatory. Actually `$.data()` method try to give you data saved for any particular DOM element. You may try above updated code and I am sure it will work for you. Let me know.

Comment: what if i have multiple interval variabel? i tried to use this script, but it's not working.. `$(".myTimer").data("timerIntvalReference", { "var1" : timerIntval, "var2" : timerIntval });` and i call the `timerReference` like this `clearinterval($(".myTimer").data("timerIntvalReference").var1)`. but it showed error something like  `undefined var1`

Comment: `$this.data("timerIntvalReference", timerIntval);` is happening in plugin context. That is it is happening per DOM element. Where you are writing `$(".myTimer").data("timerIntvalReference", { "va`? Please provide complete code. Otherwise its difficult to locate the issue.

Comment: `$(".myTimer").data("timerIntvalReference", { "var1" : timerIntval, "var2" : timerIntval2 });`

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `var timerIntval;` set the variable `timerInterval` on the `window` object, then you will have the access this variable until the next refresh.

```
window.timerIntval = setInterval(function() {
```

Then when the user clicks on any item menu you can clear it:

```
$('menu a').click(function() {
  clearInterval(window.timerIntval);
});
```

**Live example** (with multiple intervals)

```js
$('menu a').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  console.log(window.intervals);
  for (var i = 0; i < window.intervals.length; i++) {
    clearInterval(window.intervals[i]);    
  }
});

(function($) {

  $.fn.timer = function(options) {

    var defaults = {
      seconds: 60
    };

    var options = $.extend(defaults, options);

    return this.each(function() {
      if (!window.intervals) {
        window.intervals = [];  
      }
      
      var intervalId = -1;
      var seconds = options.seconds;
      var $this = $(this);

      var Timer =  {
        setTimer : function() {           
          clearInterval(intervalId);
          if(seconds <= 0) {
            alert("timeout");
          } else {
            intervalId = setInterval(function(){
              //Timer.getTimer();
              return Timer.getTimer();
            }, 1000);
            window.intervals.push(intervalId);
          }
        },
        getTimer : function () {
          if (seconds <= 0) {
            $this.html("0");
          } else {
            seconds--;
            $this.html(seconds);
          }
        }
      }

      Timer.setTimer();
    });
  };
})(jQuery);

$(".myTimer").timer({
    seconds : 100
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<menu>
  <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
</menu>

<div class="myTimer"></div>
<div class="myTimer"></div>
```

Just notice that it's little bit risky because you can only run it once otherwise the interval id of the second will override the first.

Comment: The use of `.each()` tells me that this is incorrect.  You'd need a plugin method that clears the interval, so that you can clear the interval from each element that's affected.

Comment: @WilliamChandra I was updated my answer' it's working in my snippet. Keep attention that you should replace it in any `setInterval` function (there are 2 in your code)

Comment: sorry, you should change `return Timer.setTimer();` to `return Timer.getTimer();`

Comment: @WilliamChandra ok. changed.. still working.. Any problem now?

Comment: Can you see that it works in my snippet? What is the difference between your code and mine? Can you create a snippet which reproduce the problem?

Comment: is it working for multiple element or class LIKE selector? because i load the jquery plugin in multiple element.

Comment: `Just notice that it's little bit risky because you can only run it once otherwise the interval id of the second will overide the first.` - in my answer.. You can keep all the intervals in array, or you can "listen" in the plugin to [state change](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4585031/863110) then it will clear the interval by itself, or you can store it in the `.data` model just like in the @vijayP answer

Comment: you said i can keep all the intervals in array. so how to add the intervals array to window.timerIntval?

Comment: You can push each interval to the array.. Something like: `window.intervals.push(theIntervalId)`. When user clicks on a link just loop on the array and call `clearInterval` for all of the items.

Comment: i dont get what you mean.. `window.timerIntval = setInterval(function(){
              //Timer.getTimer();
              return Timer.getTimer();
            }, 1000); window.timerIntval.push(???)`

Comment: No. `var interval = setInterval...` and then: `window.intervals.push(interval)`. I mean push the interval id into array on the window. The final goal is to keep array with all the ids.

Comment: i just dont understand using window object. it show `undefined window.intervals`. it's okay. i just follow @vijayP answer. thanks for your help and i'm very appreciate it. thankyou.