# How to detect url change without "#" symbol in javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a problem because I need to detect when my URL change and I don't find the solution. 
I have seen "window.onhashchange" but that is only for URL that contain "#" symbol. In my case, I dont have in my URL the Symbol "#" so for example, if my URL is "**/myURL/oneOption**" and change to "**/myURL/secondOption**" I need to detect that.
Somebody know how can I to do that?

Im developping a Java application and Im using HTML, CSS and Javascript (frontend). My problem is that I need to know when I press refresh button. I tried many options like that:

```
    if (window.performance) {
        console.info("window.performance works fine on this browser");
    }
    if (performance.navigation.type == 1) {
        console.info( "This page is reloaded" );
    } else {
        console.info( "This page is not reloaded");
    }
```

When I run my application and refresh the page I always see 
"window.performance works fine on this browser" and
"This page is not reloaded".
So I thought that the best opcion was check if my mouse is in the page or not (**document.onmouseover**, **document.onmouseleave**) and detect when my URL changes and in that moment call a Java function for reload my session params and show the page.
I don't know if is it the best option. If somebody could say me other way to do that will be really good for me!!

Thanks in advance.

Regards!!

Comment: Why? A new page is loaded when the URL changes ... Unless you're not playing with `history.replaceState`, your question doesn't tell.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect URL change in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6390341/how-to-detect-url-change-in-javascript)

Comment: @qxg How is that duplicate?

Comment: You can use regex for the same. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3809401/what-is-a-good-regular-expression-to-match-a-url) is a link for your reference.

Comment: @Outlaw A regex won't tell you when a URL has *changed* in the address bar.

Comment: @MrZ Usually when the URL changes the browser sends a new request to the server to load a new website. How exactly would your URL change without the page reloading, and why/how/when would you need to detect that?

Comment: Related: [How to get notified about changes of the history via history.pushState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate)

Comment: Thanks for your responses! I have updated the issue, I think that now is clearly.

Comment: Do you want to detect [1] change in url path [2] change in url hash [3] page refresh?

Comment: Thank for reply me Arghya, I need to detect when user press "F5" so will be fine detect change url path or page refresh, What do you think about that? What would be the best option?