# useEffect doesn't update state on route change

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I am looking for a solution to register the route change and apply new `state` using `setState` and `useEffect`. The current code below doesn't update functions of `setState` when the route is changed.

For example, I register the `pathname` of `/` with `location.pathname === '/'` within `createContext`, if the `pathname` is `/` the `setState` of `isHome` is registered `true`, however if `pathname` is `/page-1` `setState` is registered `false`.

On browser reloads, `onMount` the `state` is correctly set, however on a route change using `Link` this does not. Also, please note that I am using Gatsby and in doing so, importing `{ Link } from 'gatsby'`

**CreateContext.js**

```
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children, location }) => {


const prevScrollY = useRef(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isHome: location.pathname === '/',
    // other states
  });

  const detectHome = () => {
    const homePath = location.pathname === '/';
    if (!homePath) {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isHome: false
      }));
    }
    if (homePath) {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isHome: true
      }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    detectHome();
    return () => {
      detectHome();
    };
  }, [state.isHome]);

  return (
    <GlobalConsumer.Provider
      value={{
        dataContext: state,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalConsumer.Provider>
  );
};
```

If I `console.log(state.isHome)` on `pathname` `/` I get `true`, any other pathnames I get `false`, however, if I change route, the current `isHome` state remains previous, until I scroll and `useEffect` applies.

The point of registering the `isHome` state is to alter CSS per page.

How can I update state with `useEffect` when changing route. Previously, I would have done this with `componentDidUpdate` and register `prevProps.location.pathname` against `props.location.pathname`, however, my understanding is that this is no longer necessary with the `useEffect` hook.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The effect you want is  "When the location change then update my state", this is translated in `useEffect` code like this :

```
  useEffect(() => {
    detectHome();
    return () => {
      detectHome();
    };
  }, [location]);
```

Comment: But It is calling the function twice on page load. Can you please guide here?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using react-router you can subscribe to location change event in your useEffect:

```
import {browserHistory} from 'react-router';

...
useEffect(() => {
  return browserHistory.listen(detectHome);
}, []);
...
```

This would subscribe your `detectHome` function for location change on mount and unsubscribe it on unmount.

Comment: Thank you Alex, I believe Gatsby uses Reach-Router and browserHistory is not available. I will look into this further but thank you for your answer, no doubt it will help those not using Gatsby.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `GlobalProvider` as root component, in this case, it only render one time unless something change the states or props. So some explanation:

```
  useEffect(() => {
    detectHome();
    return () => {
      detectHome();
    };
  }, [state.isHome]);
```

This code above, the `state` is updated by only this `useEffect`, so it only update the state one time after first render, and the `detectHome` inside of return of `useEffect` only execute when other update happen or the `state.isHome` is different of first time. It's little confused this explanation, but that is.

But for the solution is use the 'popstate' event of window:

```
export const GlobalProvider = ({ children, location }) => {


const prevScrollY = useRef(0);
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    isHome: location.pathname === '/',
    // other states
  });

  const detectHome = () => {
    const homePath = location.pathname === '/';
    if (!homePath) {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isHome: false
      }));
    }
    if (homePath) {
      setState(prevState => ({
        ...prevState,
        isHome: true
      }));
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener('popstate', detectHome)
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('popstate', detectHome)
    };
  }, [state.isHome]);

  return (
    <GlobalConsumer.Provider
      value={{
        dataContext: state,
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </GlobalConsumer.Provider>
  );
};
```

I think that Gatsby should manipulate the history, so this will fire `popstate` of browser, and you can detect the url's changes.

Comment: Thank you Fuechter, unfortunately, this doesn't work. To further explain, the state `isHome` remains `true` or `false` and stops updating on scrolling or other event changes.

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate/4585031#4585031) worked for me.