# Is there a reliable way to intercept page changes on SPA websites?

Tags: javascript

When changing pages on an SPA, frameworks interact with the history API or sometimes trigger hash changes to track routes.

Is there a reliable way to detect that an SPA, regardless of framework, has changed routes and perhaps trigger a `CustomEvent` indicating that?

For example:

```
window.addEventListener('routechange', () => console.log('Navigation occurred'))
```

Would patching/proxying methods on the `window.history` along with detecting url signatures on hash (includes `/`?) on hashchange object suffice?

Something like:

```
const _history = window.history
window.history = new Proxy(_history, {
  get(target, key) {
    if (['pushState', 'replaceState', 'back', 'forward'].includes(key)) {
        return () => {
            window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('routechange'))
            return target[key]
        }
    }
    return target[key]
  }
})
```

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onpopstate

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get notified about changes of the history via history.pushState?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570093/how-to-get-notified-about-changes-of-the-history-via-history-pushstate)

Comment: Almost, it answers that you can monkey patch history, not that it's reliable for monitoring SPA routing through all techniques (such as hash routing, and the specific details of react/vue/angular router).

Comment: You actually can't monkey patch history anymore anyway, assigning to it is a no-op now, at least in chrome and chromium-based browsers.

Comment: Ah, but you can patch methods on it?

Comment: Yes, but your proxy idea won't work.