# How to detect change of window hash?

Tags: javascript, hash, window.location

How can you detect a `window.location.hash` onchange, for example I could do this:

```
if(window.location.hash.hasChanged())
{
   // ajax stuff
}
else
{
   // nothing, no hash has been changed (without any window reload)
}
```

If I change the hash, e.g. *edits and change the hash by pressing enter after editing* nothing happens, only on a window reload will detect a change in the hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ben Alman's [hashchange jQuery plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/) provides the ability to monitor the hash for changes.

Answer (score 17):

Most recent browsers (FF3.6+, IE8, Chrome) support the "hashchange" event on the window object - see [MDC: window.onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.onhashchange) for usage examples. Simple asynchronous listening might look like:

```
window.onhashchange = function() {
   // do something awesome here
};
```

If you want an implementation that supports older browsers, things get complicated quite quickly, and I recommend using someone else's library or plugin - see answers [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change) for several suggestions.

Comment: Glad I don't have to rely on jQuery for such a thing.