# removing # fragment identifier from address bar

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi i hope someone can help. i want to hide the fragment identifier from the address bar so instead of:

*www.mydomain.com/example.html#something*

i just get:

*www.mydomain.com/example.html*

when i click on an anchor tag.

I have looked at lots of related questions and forums but still can't quite figure it out. I'm pretty sure i should be using something along the lines of:

```
window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,''); //and or .hash
```

put just cannot figure it out.

[localScroll](http://flesler.blogspot.com/2007/10/jquerylocalscroll-10.html) plugin allows you to hide or keep the identifiers and by default they are hidden. i think many gallery plugins have a similar option too.

but when i try and do it myself (bit of a novice) i get crazy to no results.

below is some basic example script i would like it to work with:

```
<style>
.wrap{
width:300px;
height:200px;
margin:auto;
}

.box{
width:300px;
height:200px;
position:absolute;
display:none;
}

#one{background:red;}
#two{background:blue;}
#three{background:green;}

.load{display:block;}
</style>


<body>
<ul>
    <li><a href="#one">One</a></li>
    <li><a href="#two">Two</a></li>
    <li><a href="#three">Three</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="wrap">
    <div id="one" class="box load">This is Box 1</div>
    <div id="two" class="box">This is Box 2</div>
    <div id="three" class="box">This is Box 3</div>
</div>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$("ul li a").click(function(){

       $("div.box").fadeOut(1000);

       $($(this).attr('href')).fadeIn(1000);

    });
});
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: I'm not too clear on what you're trying to do, to be honest. Your code seems to be working well.

Comment: duplicity http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Add

```
return false;
```

at the end of your click function, it will stop this event propagation

Comment: +1 -- I posted a big long answer about the hash tag stuff, but now that I've actually read his code, I see that your solution will give him the behavior he wants. :-)

Comment: thank you very much, so annoying it was that simple. i think looking at other peoples questions and google got me confused and sidetracked

Answer (score 3):

the `replace` function returns a new string, it doesn't operate on the old one. You need to use: `window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'')`.

However, this will not have the expected effect, as changing window.location.href in any way that's not just adding or changing a hash tag causes a page reload.

The localScroll plugin works by searching for the hashtag and using the jQuery scrollTo plugin to scroll to the location, and preventing the default behavior of the browser when you click on a link with a hash tag. They haven't actually changed the URL to remove the hash, they've prevented it from ever appearing.

The best you can do if you want to remove the hash from the URI is to keep just the # at the end:

```
window.location.href = window.location.href.replace(/#.*/,'#');
```

Although in some older browsers, even this will trigger a page reload (only very old browsers, though).

Comment: although return false; was what was needed, thank you for your answer. its helped explain what localScroll was doing and why what i was trying was not working.

Answer (score 0):

try this....it will remove # globally in your url

```
window.location.href.replace(/\#*/g, "")
```

here is  [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/Gyqxu/)

Comment: `example.html#something` -> `example.htmlsomething` ? Probably not a good idea `:)`

Comment: no its not like that i have written the same thing in local file so i just copy paste that and did this mistake :)

Comment: The replace function returns a *new* string with the replacement. You need to assign the result somewhere.

Comment: it's his problem not mine, we are here to tell what could be right way to achieve the output regarding to the question..