# Fragment URL transformation

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-bbq

I have the BBQ plugin working already, so this is just a cosmetic change. I have no idea how to transform the URL from `/index.html#pages/index.html` to just `/index.html#index`

It's basically a fragment transformation I guess, but am very new to JS. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

You can access the hash just using window.location.hash and it returns a string so you can do whatever string manipulation you like on it. For Example:

```
var temp = window.location.hash; // == #pages/index.html
temp = temp.replace("pages/","").replace(".html","");
window.location.hash = temp; //sets the hash to #index
```

Comment: @Pepe Did you set `hashchange` event?

Comment: You can. This is just the code to manipulate the hash. You didn't mention onhashchange in your question? If it is you should explain how you want to use it. I found some info about onhashchange for you and I can change my answer to include it once I know what you expecting. It looks like jquery has a good onhashchange event. Some info here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change