# Javascript: Need to detect when a user revisits the page with a changed hash tag

Tags: javascript, hyperlink, hashtag

Problem is (at least with my current browser), changing the hash tag and entering the new url doesn't trigger a refresh of the page, and thus I'm not aware offhand how to detect when this hash tag change has been made.

Is there an elegant way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a nasty-ish solution, but you can poll the URL for a change every so often:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;

function poll() {
  if (window.location.hash != hash) {
    hash = window.location.hash;

    // Hash has changed. Do stuff here.
  }
}

setInterval(poll, 100);
```

Comment: Sadly, afaict. There might be an event, but I doubt it's supported by IE.

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Answer (score 1):

Check for a new `location.hash`

Comment: Every 100 milliseconds or something?

Comment: Lol, that's *exactly* what I set my interval to!