# Add a URL to browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to set a URL on the browser back button.  I've looked at a few examples and found this code and it works.  The problem is when I click on an anchor button it does the same as when I click on the browser back button.. this is not good. I believe the problem is with this line of code - I could be wrong -

```
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event){ ... })
```

Here's the code -

```
history.pushState(null, null, '<?php echo $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]; ?>');
window.addEventListener('popstate', function(event) {
        window.location.assign("http://newurl.com");
});
```

I've been working on this all day and cannot find a solution.  Can someone help?

Answer (score 2):

This answer is already given, but I will try to explain what I understand using `pushState`.

Consider your url is "`google.com/gmail`"

1. Make currentURL as temp URL, so your browser will show this URL. At this step, there will be one URL in the stack i.e `google.com/gmail#!/tempURL`.

   `history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname+"#!/tempURL");`
2. Push the previousURL as new state so now your browser will show previousURL i.e `google.com/gmail`.

   `history.pushState(null, document.title, location.pathname);`

   Current state of the stack:

   1. First element : `google.com/gmail`
   2. Last element :  `google.com/gmail#!/tempURL`
3. Now add listener to listen event

   ```
   window.addEventListener("popstate", function() {
       if(location.hash === "#!/tempURL") {
           history.replaceState(null, document.title, location.pathname);
           //replaces first element of last element of stack with google.com/gmail so can be used further
           setTimeout(function(){
               location.replace("http://www.yahoo.com/");
           },0);
       }
   }, false);
   ```

[How to change url and detect the back button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7538477/how-to-change-url-and-detect-the-back-button)

Comment: Can someone look at the code I posted that WORKS.  Then tell me why anchors buttons when clicked redirect to the back button url?