# How to restrict browser back functionality caused by mouse side buttons?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an application which presents the user with a set of questionnaires, displayed using frames. I want to restrict the users from navigating back/forward using mouse side buttons, there are navigation buttons on each of the frames and I don't want to jeopardise the functionality of the buttons when restricting mouse side buttons.

I have already restricted the browser back functionality from keyboard using javascript, but cannot restrict mouse side buttons.

Comment: You can probably catch the event using some javascript onclick method but I don't see why you need it. You can't ever stop someone from going back

Comment: And why are you using frames? This the 21st century

Comment: *"How to restrict browser back functionality.."*  Why not create a web-app. that does not have the user cursing you, your children & your children's children?  Or to put that another way, design your web-app. so that it does not break when the user hits the back button.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that [this person was having the same problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser) and here is the solution that was presented to him >

```
window.onload = function () {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
        history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
        window.onpopstate = function () {
            history.pushState('newjibberish', null, null);
            // Handle the back (or forward) buttons here
            // Will NOT handle refresh, use onbeforeunload for this.
        };
    }
    else {
        var ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.onhashchange = function () {
            if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                ignoreHashChange = true;
                window.location.hash = Math.random();
                // Detect and redirect change here
                // Works in older FF and IE9
                // * it does mess with your hash symbol (anchor?) pound sign
                // delimiter on the end of the URL
            }
            else {
                ignoreHashChange = false;   
            }
        };
    }
}
```