# Detect if user brought to a page while clicking back button

Tags: django

In Django views,is it possible to detect whether a user brought to a page by clicking the back button of the browser ?

Comment: Usually when user click a back button browsers just bring the pages straight from their cache, without hitting the server again at all. I think detecting this in JavaScript would be a much better bet.

Answer (score 2):

You can also add no-cache header to your page and your site always be render.

I do it by middleware like this:

```
class MustRevalidate(object):
   def process_response(self, request, response):
     response['Cache-Control'] = 'no-cache, must-revalidate, no-store'
     response['Pragma'] = 'no-cache'
     return response
```

And now you can check somewhere in your views request.META['HTTP_REFERER'].

Answer (score 1):

You can check [request.META['HTTP_REFERER']](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.META) on the server-side, but if the browser already has a page in cache, it's not going to do a full GET request - it's going to retrieve the page from its internal cache.

Your only option to detect the back button click is on the client-side via JavaScript. See [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser) for some ideas on how you can detect the event and then do whatever processing you need, like making an Ajax call to the server-side.