# How can I add fixed Menubar with jsf

Tags: facebook, jsf, primefaces, menubar

I'm working in project with jsf and javamail and I want a fixed menubar which includes(Inbox, Sent, Draft...).

This is my goal; I want to add fixed menubar that does not change between all the pages exactly like Facebook bar, it means the menubar still fixed and the content of the page change.

Comment: You might need something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443883/primefaces-ajax-navigation-with-browser-history-hashtag/20760830#20760830

Comment: What is the version of your JSF ?

Comment: i use the last version of JSF

Answer (score 0):

Please try looking at
[Layout mailbox example from primefaces showcase here](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/layoutMailbox.jsf)