# Load different jsf page on click of a list item

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, primefaces

I am new to JSF. I have a unordered list and a div.

```
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="#TestPage">Test Page</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">item3</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="content"></div>
```

Now on click of the list items I want to load different xhtml pages using JSF. Is it possible to achieve this usecase? I am using JSF 2.0 and primefaces.

Comment: see this please
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20443883/primefaces-ajax-navigation-with-browser-history-hashtag/20760830#20760830

Comment: I don't understand the concrete problem. How exactly does it form a problem to you to just use `<a href="somepage.xhtml">` the usual way ...? Are you new to HTML as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just replace the plain HTML link by a JSF `h:link`. According to the [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/h/link.html):

> Render an HTML "a" anchor element. The value of the component is rendered as the anchor text and the outcome of the component is used to determine the target URL rendered in the "href" attribute.

```
<li><h:link outcome="TestPage" value="Test Page" /></li>
```

Where the `outcome` attribute specifies the target navigation case.

**See also:**

- [Implicit navigation in JSF 2](http://balusc.blogspot.com.es/2011/09/communication-in-jsf-20.html#ImplicitNavigation)

---

Note that's useful for using JSF navigation cases. If you want to just perform a *GET* request for an external non-JSF url, just use the plain HTML way.

Answer (score 0):

On `click` event of `<li>` element, you can call `$('#content').load(Url, successEventHandler)`

Comment: Why JavaScript / jQuery for such a simple task?

Comment: @Alex: OP originally tagged question with jQuery (which indeed doesn't make much sense). See question edit history.