# How to get a link to change after each click?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, methods, random, hyperlink

I have a random webpage link below that works if you reload the page each time and don't hit the "back" button on your browser. Is there a way to get this to be a new link every click by using Ruby/Rails? Or would this be something I'd have to use JS or something for? Reason I ask is because I have no experience with any other languages. Maybe there is a way to auto_reload the webpage every 10 seconds or something similar?

Webpage Model

```
class Webpage < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :link

 def self.randomize_webpages
  all.shuffle.first.link
 end
end
```

WebpagesController

```
def index
  @webpages = Webpage.all
end
```

View

```
<%= link_to 'Take Me Anywhere But Here', @random_page %>
```

CSV

CSV seeder for Webpage

```
link
http://www.buzzfeed.com
http://www.reddit.com
http://boston.com
http://phys.org
http://www.popsci.com
http://www.technologyreview.com
http://techcrunch.com
View Index.html.erb
```

Answer (score 1):

In your controller, you could set `@random_page` within `index`:

```
def index
  @random_page = Webpage.randomize_webpages
end
```

This would call this method to return a random link on each load of `index`:

```
class Webpage < ActiveRecord::Base
 validates_presence_of :link

 def self.randomize_webpages
  all.sample.link
 end
end
```

Comment: Right i have done that setup but my problem now is that the link remains the same if you hit the "back" button on your browser

Comment: In this case, you'll want to use JavaScript, though this may be a difficult problem to solve.  Check this out, it may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser

Comment: Thanks I will check that out and see if I can implement it. In the meantime the following is a rough solution but it works if placed in appropriate view: <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5" />