# How does Google Play Music web app handle routing

Tags: routes, polymer-1.0

I am building a single page application and I am looking to imitate the routing achieved by the Google Play Music page. When the user loads up my page I would like them to receive all of the HTML needed and then dynamically load data as they navigate the page.

To maintain a users navigation history I need the page to have a way to manage the back button functionality and URL routing. What can I use to handle new the URL entry when there is only one page served to the user?

If you are familiar with the Google Music page you will see that a combination of the URL and loading spinners are used. This tells the user that the page is loading but they never actually leave the original page.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3354511/1546934), you can accomplish this using the [HTML5 history API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API). The things you need to pay attention to on that page are the `pushState()` method and the `popstate` event.

Using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10050826/1546934) as a template, some code that you may write to accomplish this might look as follows:

```
window.onload = function() {
    if (typeof history.pushState === "function") {
        history.pushState("jibberish", null, null);
        window.onpopstate = function(event) {
            // you should deal with the back button in here
            history.pushState("state object or string", "Title", "/some-page");
        };
    }
    else {
        // for browsers that don't support history
        var ignoreHashChange = true;
        window.onhashchange = function() {
            if (!ignoreHashChange) {
                ignoreHashChange = true;
                window.location.hash = Math.random();
            }
            else {
                ignoreHashChange = false;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

This will prevent the user from pressing the back button, instead sending them to `domain/hello` in modern browsers. For your use case you might want to use `event.state` to keep track of where you are and whether the previous page was from your app or not.