# Bigcommerce search form resets browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery, search-engine, bigcommerce

I have a store on Bigcommerce and have ran into an issue. If you search for a product on the store, jump to any page number after 1, click on a product to get a description, and then hit the browsers back button, you will be taken back to the 1st results page. I would like for it to take you back to the page you were last at instead of being back to square 1. Does any body know a javascript code that could help.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what ever you want to do on browser back button click, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser) is the example. You can save state on local storage or where ever you want and than use this state info to go back to your previous page.

Or you can use your back end code to do the same.

Comment: thanks for the directions. I still am not getting it right though. I am an amateur when it comes to javascript and AJAX. I just don't know where exactly to put the code as everything is split up by template files.