# window.event.clientX and window.event.clientY is undefind when i am clicking on page

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    debugger;
    if (window.event) {
        if (window.event.clientX < 40 && window.event.clientY < 0) {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        } else {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
    } else {
        if (event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 1) {
            alert("Browser refresh button is clicked...");
        }
        if (event.currentTarget.performance.navigation.type == 2) {
            alert("Browser back button is clicked...");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: What would you expect? You need to access the clientX in a click event, not a pageload event. clientX is a [mouse event property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/clientX)

Comment: I want to reset my all filed on click of back button of browser. That's why i am identifying is it page refresh or it is back button click.

Comment: That is important information - right now it is an X/Y problem. Perhaps you could look for "detect back or refresh" like this one http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser

Comment: Exactly @mplungjan . I want to detect page refresh or  page back button.