# Iframe and browser back button

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a main page that contains several iframes and those iframes also have multiple iframes. iframes load with dynamic data.now the requirement is that when i click on the back button of browser then that give an alert(this functionality is not allowed). so that the previous iframe can't load. so how can i do this??

Comment: Simply dont use iframes...

Comment: first why you are using `iframes` when u have other option as `div`.

Comment: @Jonasw Sometimes you have no choice when it comes to handle third party widget and this has nothing to do with question

Comment: Look at [window history api](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/history) using pushstate and popstate event

Comment: using history is not reliable when user refreshes window it keeps adding to history array

Answer (score 2):

Based on iFrame purpose which is an HTML document embedded inside another HTML document. So an IFrame behaves like a window with its own independent content. In jQuery I did this and works for me. hope that would be useful.

```
$(window.parent.window).on('popstate', function () {               
    //Some codes
});
```

But should know that "popstate" event of the window is fired when the active history entry changes. So it works for both backward and forward navigation.

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have no prior condition to check iframe content

```
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return 'this functionality is not allowed';
}
```

Comment: This event is fired not only on backward navigation. It would be fired if you close tab/window, forward or refresh

Comment: hmm I know, but that's the first solution come to my mind. Looking for further enhancements do you have any idea ? :)

Comment: Something like [that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18382442/1414562) but would really depends OP expected behaviour

Comment: that's a polyfill for onbeforeunload  method.

Comment: I thinks we have done our job let the OP to decides his way :)