# How to tell if browser's forward or backward button is clicked?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

In React, I want to do something only if **back button** is clicked but what actually happening is it gets invoked on both back and forward buttons on the browser.

This is what I tried, but it gets called on both back and forward button clicks

```
window.onpopstate = () => {
  someFunction();
};
```

Is there a way to check if it is back button only or forward button only?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6359327/detect-back-button-click-in-browser

Comment: @jarmod that is not related.... unless one of those questions seems to answer it and I missed it....

Comment: I saw that question. it didn't help me though.  I want to know specifically which of them is clicked.. @jarmod