# How to open a hidden div when a hash is on the URL?

Tags: javascript, html, hash

I'm using this javascript code to have a couple "show/hide" toggled divs on my site:

```
<script language="javascript"> 
function toggledean() {
    var ele = document.getElementById("toggleTextdean");
    var text = document.getElementById("displayTextdean");

    if(ele.style.display == "block") {
        ele.style.display = "none";
        text.innerHTML = "Show more";
    } 
    else {
        ele.style.display = "block";
        text.innerHTML = "Hide";
    }
} 
</script>
```

What should I add to this code to have the div be displayed upon loading the page with a specific #hash added to the URL?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Translation: Please do it for me and I guarantee it will work if you're right.

Comment: @jared I'm sorry, I didn't mean for it to come off like that. I've been researching this for a few hours without luck and I'm very new to JavaScript so I thought I'd post here for some help. I didn't think that was too terrible.

Comment: If you're not averse to jQuery, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change.

Answer (score 7):

This is not the javascript answer that you want, but you could try playing around with the `:target` pseudo selector. For instance,

```
<!-- HTML -->
<div id="foo">show this with #foo.</div>
<div id="bar">#bar shows this.</div>

<style type="text/css">
    div {display: none}
    :target {display: block}
</style>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZAHns/4/ (thanks to Jared for the idea of adding the anchors).

Depending on what you are trying to do, this could possibly work, but think your requirements through.

Note: Take this response with a HUGE grain of salt -- don't use it.

---

To answer the actual question, use the following to determine if the hash is present:

```
var in_hash = location.hash.slice(1) === what_you_are_looking_for;
if (in_hash) ? /* IN HASH */ : /* NOT IN HASH */;
```

Comment: @mikeycgto Good point. Not supported in IE makes it ONE of the issues with using this. ;)

Comment: @Jared Farrish Silly me! Genius to add the anchor tag... I'll add both, edit my answer, and credit you. Thanks!

Comment: JavaScript can always override the `:target` rule. I gather he'll still need to use the function to toggle the divs later somehow... (I think both can be used together, though)

Comment: Reality is, it's probably not that easy; what if the OP needs a cross-browser, CSS2(ish) answer? What then?

Comment: I added the fact that this shouldn't at all be used, it was just a little thought. The fact that IE doesn't support :target is a deal breaker in itself but for the record, :target's support list: Firefox (1.0+), Safari (3.1+), Opera (9.5+), Chrome [http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target].

Comment: @tjeezy May I say than nowadays your answer is the perfect solution? http://caniuse.com/#search=%3Atarget

Comment: @mizurnix While this accomplishes the question asked, this is probably not the best way to go about showing / hiding different things.

Answer (score 6):

Something like this *should* work:

```
<script>
    var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash) {
        document.getElementById(hash).style.display = 'block'
    }
</script>
```

If you've only got the one element, like your script has, you could just call the function to toggle it if any hash exists in the url:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
   function toggledean() {
    ...
    } 
    if (window.location.hash == '#dean') toggledean(); 
</script>
```

Or you could make your toggle script a little more universal:

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');   

function toggle (elementPartial) {

    var ele = document.getElementById('toggleText'+elementPartial);
    var text = document.getElementById('displayText'+elementPartial);
    if(ele.style.display == 'block') {
        ele.style.display = 'none';
        text.innerHTML = 'Show more';
    } else {
        ele.style.display = 'block';
        text.innerHTML = 'Hide';
    }
} 

if (hash) {
    toggle(hash); 
}

</script>
```

Additionally, you could make this a little simpler and more flexible using a javascript framework, like jQuery.

Comment: location.hash includes the actual hash character, so this solution (the use of getElementById(...)) will most likely not work unless the prepended hash character is accounted for.

Comment: Man, that's digging up the past @schlimmchen... I don't even remember writing that. Made some amendments based on that info.

Comment: I did not want to bother you, @hellodaniel. I found this question despite its age and your answer helped in my own javascript quest, but I just recognized it had this flaw... Thanks for amending it!

Comment: I was able to use:
````
var hash = window.location.hash.replace('#', '');
    if (hash) {
        document.getElementById(hash).classList.add("bio-open");
    }
````
But the other functions on this page no longer work, so I can't close the window this script opened

Answer (score 0):

Others have answered the URL hash part, I'll just comment on the script:

```
> <script language="javascript">
```

The language attribute is deprecated, type is required, so:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

> function toggledean() {
>     var ele = document.getElementById("toggleTextdean");
>     var text = document.getElementById("displayTextdean");
> 
>     if(ele.style.display == "block") {
```

The default *display* property is '' (empty string) unless you have set it to "block" previously.

```
>         ele.style.display = "none";
>         text.innerHTML = "Show more";
>     } else {
>         ele.style.display = 'block';
>         text.innerHTML = 'Hide';
>     }
```

Given the very high probability that the div will have a display value of '' when first loaded, you are much better off testing for `style.display = 'none'`, so:

```
if (ele.style.display == 'none') {
    ele.style.display = '';
    text.innerHTML = 'Hide';

} else {
    ele.style.display = 'none';
    text.innerHTML = 'Show more';
}
```