# Show element based on hash in the url

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, hash

I have a page (/categories.html) with about 50 p elements :

```
<p id='BCI'>Blue_colored_items</p>
<p id='RCI'>Red_colored_items</p>
...
```

Now, I want the page to only show

```
Blue_colored_items
```

if

```
/categories.html#BCI
```

is the requested url, and so on.

How should I get that working? I can change the entire html.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I just found [this pure css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6894125/how-to-open-a-hidden-div-when-a-hash-is-on-the-url) working very well.

```
<style>
p {display: none}
:target {display: block}
</style>
```

Anyway, thanks for your answers, Rory and Andrei.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.classList.add(window.location.hash.substring(1))
```

will add any existing hash as a class to your `<body>` element, allowing you control using CSS:

```
p {display:none;}
.BCI p#BCI {display: inline;}
.RCI p#RCI {display: inline;}
...
```

Or, you could simply search the `<p>` based on hash and display it:

```js
// hardcoding hash for StackOverflow (only needed here, on SO):
window.location.hash = '#BCI';

let p = document.getElementById(window.location.hash.substring(1));
if (p) p.style.display = 'inline';
```

```css
p { display: none; }
```

```html
<p id='BCI'>Blue_colored_items</p>
<p id='RCI'>Red_colored_items</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get the value from the `window.location.hash` property. Then you can hide the content you require excluding the specified element, something like this:

```js
var hash = '#BCI'; // window.location.hash;

$('p').not(hash).hide();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="BCI">Blue_colored_items</p>
<p id="RCI">Red_colored_items</p>
```

Note that `p` is a very generic selector I used only for this example. I'd suggest something much more specific for your production code.