# How do i make JQuery react when the hashtag in the url changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've been trying to implement a history plugin called really simple history, and I think I've succeeded with that. So now I want to make my ajax to react when the history changes (you press the back or forward button.)

I think I should use the hash tag in the URL for this, but I'm very open for other suggestions.

Anyways **how do I load my ajax when the hash tag changes without having reloading the page?**

Comment: Have a look at other jquery history plugins like http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/ and see how they do it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [address jquery plugin](http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/) and its `.change()` functionality

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to use any plugins to get it to work.

From [On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    .. work ..
});
```

Answer (score 0):

im not sure if i understand what you want, but with RSH when the hash changes the function you added with `dhtmlHistory.addListener(someFunction);` gets executed.