# Navigation when loading outside content into a div

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, hash, navigation

I'm trying to load my content into a div using Ajax. So far I've been successful into getting it to load. However, I don't know how to handle when...

1. The user inputs the url (http://www.example.com/#page.html) is should direct them to
   the page with the correct content loaded. (Right now it just loads it normally.)
2. When the user hits the BACK button on their browser it should navigate properly.

Any suggestions and concerns are welcome also. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: for claryfication to case B: What does you mean with 'should navigate properly' ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**case A**

Upon loading the page, let JavaScript check whether or not there is a hash present and act accordingly. Load content based on hash if there is a hash, otherwise show default page. ( be sure to validate the hash! )

```
var hash = window.location.hash /* get the hash from the url */
```

**case B**

Assuming you're constantly browsing 'from hash to hash', the browser should already do this correctly. Requirement is that you implement case A as described above.

---

**Example:**

1. You visit example.com
2. You click through to **example.com/**#MyAwesomeAjaxLoadedContent
3. You click through to **example.com/**#MoreAwesomeAjaxContent
4. You click the back button, you're now at
   **example.com/**#MyAwesomeAjaxLoadedContent

If you implemented case A correctly, your browser should now display **example.com/**#*MyAwesomeAjaxLoadedContent*

Comment: But if I'm using Ajax and not causing postbacks then I can't do it on pageload right?

Comment: Check the hash on pageload, for cases that occur after the initial pageload, take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change