# IE7 window.location.hash issue

Tags: jquery, ajax, internet-explorer-7, hashtag

in my new project, site loads pages using ajax by reading hash tags,
to do this using that small javascript code;

```
$(window).bind("hashchange",function(){
            var hash= window.location.hash;
            var target = hash.substring(2);
            $("#ajaxArea").empty().load(target);            
            });
```

but in ie7 it doesn't work..
is there any other way to handle this problem in ie7?.

thanks..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just get a plugin that adds hashchange event support to IE7, eg. http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/

Answer (score 0):

This question looks like it's already been adequately discussed on this very site:
[On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)