# Make jQuery wait for href change before it reads href?

Tags: jquery

Imagine the following markup:

```
<a href="#link01">1</a>
<a href="#link02">2</a>
```

And:

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var href = $(location).attr('href'),
   hrefLenght = href.length,
   hrefPos = href.indexOf("#"),
   hrefPage = href.slice(hrefPos+1);
   alert(hrefPage);
});
```

Now, what happens after you click a link is that jQuery alerts the `hrefPage` which was there **before** you clicked the link, not **after**, as expected. Therefore:

1) I'm located at `http://www.example.com/#link01`
2) I click a link
3, result) `link01` is echoed
3, expected) `link02` is echoed

Any ideas how to fix this?

EDIT: Why am I using location instead of href? Because I want the aforementioned code to work also when the page loads with the href without anything having been clicked at all and I don't think it's a good idea to write two pieces of code for the same process?

Comment: You're trrying to implement a "page location changed" handler with a link-clicked handler. It doesn't work that way. For starters, `click` fires _first_, but there are other reasons that it can never work. Just take the link's `href` property instead.

Comment: No, a click handler for a link won't magically trigger just because you loaded the page. If you want to avoid code duplication, encapsulate the logic in a function and call it in multiple handlers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the `hashchange` event to monitor these changes instead:

```
$('a').bind('hashchange',function(){ 
    var hval = location.hash.slice(1); // remove the leading #
    alert(hval);
});
```

To trigger the `hashchange` on page load, so it fires for external links to the hash or when you browse with the back button (instead of only when a link is clicked), add this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).trigger('hashchange');
});
```

Comment: It does work in IE8+ -- older versions need [a plugin](http://stackoverflow.com/q/680785/901048).

Answer (score 2):

You have a bug in your code. Instead of `this` keyword you are using `location` which points to `window.location`.

```
$('a').click(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href'),
   hrefLenght = href.length,
   hrefPos = href.indexOf("#"),
   hrefPage = href.slice(hrefPos+1);
   alert(hrefPage);
});
```

Comment: I think he meant for that, though this is a valid fix for the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the `href` of the link you clicked? it will have the value that the href will have after it changes.

```
$('a').click(function(){
  var href = this.href,
  hrefLength = href.length,
  hrefPos = href.indexOf("#"),
  hrefPage = href.slice(hrefPos+1);
  alert(hrefPage);
  // could also use:
  // alert(this.href.split("#")[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to get the url to change before the javascript is run. One way you could do this is to simply put

```
window.location = $(this).attr('href');
```

at the top of the javascript code to force the window navigation action to happen before your javascript

example: http://jsfiddle.net/btdqe/