# Making a Hashtag listener

Tags: jquery

Something which doesn't take up too much memory that always listens to the pageurl #hashtag and arguments can be binded accordingly.

I want to avoid calling a listener, the listener should always be listening.

I suppose `setTimeout()` can be used, but not sure if that's such a wise idea on the memory, what do you think?

Looking for something like onChange event for the Browser URL.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/680785/422184

Answer (score 0, accepted):

check out jQuery Address that should be exactly what you want.

http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/