# jquery: How to hange hash tag / address bar name for cycle script

Tags: jquery, cycle, hashtag

please can someone help me with changing the hash tag.

I am using the jquery `.cycle` script and my pages are sliding correctly to the next div which is fine, but at the moment, the address bar stays the same i.e. `www.blahblah.com` whether I am on the contact page or about us page, can someone please help me so that when I click contact us button, the address bar will change to `www.blahblah.com/contact_us`, I would like to do this for each page wit home being `www.blahblah.com/index.html`.

The second part to my question is how do I get the home button working so that it slides back the other way.

I'm very new to all this so if you could put a demo on jsfiddle or paste a working code, this will help me drastically. I only seem to earn by taking working code and chopping and changing it but for the life of me can't get this to work the way I want.

Here's the link to the **[jsfiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mYmrx/16/)**.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change the url hash using:

```
window.location.hash = 'whatever';
```

You can bind on hashchange an do whatever you want using (jQuery):

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {   
   // Change the page here.... 
});
```

I personally mostly use the [backbone](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/) framework for this kind of applications. Backbone has a thing called a 'router' which handles hash changes and such. Maybe you should check it out.

Also, check out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/680785/508702) post.

Comment: Hi THanks for replying, i've taken a look at both comments but i'm really new to js and i don't understand enough yet, could you please please give me a demo of it working, i can then play about with it and understand it more. Thanks for what you've done.

Comment: Check out the links in my post. On the backbone page you can find some examples to get you going.

Comment: Hi Baszz, thanks for replying again but i've spent days looking at it and i can't get any further i hate to give up, so if you've got an idiots guide you can help me with i'll be stuck for months lol

Answer (score 1):

You could probably extend the script using [html5 pushstate](http://diveintohtml5.info/history.html).

The API is pretty easy. First argument is the state object, second the window title and third the url. For instance:

`history.pushState(null, null, "/contact")`

Comment: Hi THanks for replying, i've taken a look at both comments but i'm really new to js and i don't understand enough yet, could you please please give me a demo of it working, i can then play about with it and understand it more. Thanks for what you've done.