# wait for the url to change on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, window.location

I have an image, on clicking the image the URL changes but the page is not reloaded(partial navigation). I have used `window.location.href` that fetches the current URL, but it displays the previous URL on console log. I want to fetch the URL after it changes.

Am I missing some window wait event?

Comment: When you say partial navigation, is some type of AJAX occurring, or are you simply changing the hash of the url?

Comment: The URL remains the same just the # changes

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To retrieve the new hash of the page, use [location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/DOM/Window.location):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

For a similar requirement in the past, I've used [Ben Alman's hashChange plugin](http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-hashchange-plugin/). Once the plugin is included on page, you can attach code to the `hashChange` event:

```
$(window).hashchange( function(){
    // Your code here
})
```

Here's [a working fiddle to demonstrate](http://jsfiddle.net/4nVxA/).

**Additional Information**

This SO post is worth reading: [On - window.location.hash - change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

**Note**

If you don't want to use a plugin, you'll have to post your markup before I can provide an alternative solution.

Comment: but it will fetch the hash of the previous URL. my hash changes every time i click on different image. i have to fetch the URL after it gets changed by click event.

Comment: @subhojit777, I've updated my answer to reflect your concerns. Will this meet your needs?

Comment: thanks for the last link. i knew that there was some problem with event.

Answer (score 0):

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
var loc = window.location.href+hash;
window.location=loc;
```