# In Javascript (jquery), is there a way to detect when the page anchor changes?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically, I want to have links throughout the page that change the anchor -- the part of the URL after a # symbol. When that part of the URL changes, the JavaScript should respond.

I could add an onclick method to every link, but is there a better way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/680865/1267663 if that's of use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's not an anchor, it's the hash?

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
    alert('My fracking hash changed to : '+document.location.hash);
});
```

Comment: Ugh, onhashchange. Thanks, I was looking for something like onanchorchange. I thought the text after the hash was called the anchor. Thanks.

Comment: Nope, it's the hash, and yes, it's the `onhashchange` event that is triggered everytime it changes. And it's available for setting/getting in the `document.location.hash`.

Answer (score 4):

```
$(window).bind('hashchange', function() {
  // code here
});
```

think that should do it

Answer (score 1):

In jQuery you don't need to add onclick events to all links individual. With a selector like `$('a')` you could add an event to all of your links at once.

```
$('a').click(function(){
    // code here
});
```

Inside this event you can use the `$(this)` object to get the `href`.

But I suggest that the other answers show you a more elegant way for solving this problem.

Answer (score 0):

you can add a [delegate](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) to `a`,

$(elements).on(events, selector, data, handler);

the difference is it won't add "`onClick`" to every `a` element, but it will catch the "`onClick`" event of `a`

Answer (score 0):

First of all you have to pick the element.

For example var links = $("a");

Then you add the jquery function .click()

Answer (score 0):

Try this

1. Store `window.location.hash` on a global variable, say, `currentHash`
2. Create a function to check `window.location.hash !== currentHash`
3. If the check fails set `currentHash = window.location.hash`
4. Execute this function using `setInterval` on `DOMReady`

Answer (score 0):

[Sammy.js](http://sammyjs.org/) is your friend here. I've used it on a SPA I'm working on and I love it!