# How do I show my hidden div using this jquery code?

Tags: jquery, css, html, hide, show

I have a jquery code to display one div and hide the rest dynamically on the same page. And im having a little problem, when i only try to acess directly(via url) to the login page index.php#login im sent back to the main page index.php#home

This happens because the login as to be set as hidden. So is there anyway i can go around this?

```
    $('#w').live('click', function(){

        $('#b').css('display','none');
        $('#a').css('display','block');
    });

    $('#x').live('click', function(){
        $('#a').css('display','none');
        $('#b').css('display','block');
    });

<li><a href="#home" id=w>Home</a></li>
<li><a href="#login" id=x>Login</a></li>

<div id=b style="display:none;">

// Login

</div>

<div id=a>

// Main content

</div>
```

Ps: Sorry for my bad english

Comment: From [jQuery API](http://api.jquery.com/live/): "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  // set all event binding
  $('body').on('click', 'a[href="#home"], a[href="#login"]', function() {
       $('#a, #b').toggle(0);
  });

  // try to fire appropriate event using hash value

  var hash = window.location.hash; // return:  #home  OR #login
  $('a[href="'+ hash +'"]').click();

});
```

May be you can get more from ***[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change).***

#### Note

But not sure, why you need `live` event. `live` event needs for bind event to dynamically loaded content ie. element(s) that append to DOM after page load.

If you really need a live delegate event then instead of `live` use [*`.on()`*](http://api.jquery.com/on/) for that cause `live` is deprecated and try to use jQuery latest version.

If  you think you don't need `live` then simplify the event handler like:

```
$('a[href="#home"], a[href="#login"]').on('click', function() {
    $('#a, #b').toggle(0);
});
```