# Jquery hash change url slider

Tags: jquery, url, hash, slider

I have used the following code to change the url hash as I click through my slider, however I am now wondering if it is possible that when a user changes the slide number themselves in the url, the slide will change according to the entered hash, sort of the reverse of what i have already, any help is very appreciated thanks.

```
var hash = $(".active").data("id");
location.hash = hash;
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is the [onhashchange](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onhashchange)-event.

It's not supported in [all browsers versions](http://caniuse.com/hashchange), but you could use a polyfill (there are plenty available for jQuery), or you could do a simple feature detection like this

```
if ("onhashchange" in window) {
    $(window).bind( 'hashchange', function(e) { })
}
```