# Is there something like "onpathchange"?

Tags: html, html5-history

When using hash fragments for url manipulation with javascript, you can simply detect all changes in the url fragment part using `onhashchange` event. Is there any similar way to detect changes in the path part of url using HTML5 history API?

I know, I can override handling clicks on anchor elements, override back button behaviour, but what if the user edits url by hand?

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Comment: The `onbeforeunload` might be what you need: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.onbeforeunload

Comment: But, is it possible to cancel the unload in the `onbeforeunload` handler?

Comment: @SamuelHapak You can not forbid user from navigating out.

Comment: @Passerby but that means, that `onbeforeunload` is totally unusable for Ajax navigation (that is navigating to another page without reloading) in single page applications.

Comment: @SamuelHapak You can't "navigate to another page without reloading". Once navigated, the life cycle of current page is finished, and every script context is discarded. You can use AJAX to **modify page content** without navigating (i.e. not touching the URL of the page, except for the hash part), but you can't, by any means, forbids user from navigating out.

Comment: @Passerby I do understand that I can't forbid the user from navigating out. But when he changes only the hash portion of the URL, I can notice it and change the page without navigation away. As HTML5 adds possibility to change the path portion of URL without navigating away, I was curious, whether it is possible to suppress the page reload in cases, where user do not change the domain part of the url, but only the path part.