# how to create a link to a specific tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

[**Demo link please click here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/x9ypj/)

I am trying to create a link like this `page1.html#section1, page2.html#section2` etc., but these link not working

**Associated code**

```
function showSection( sectionID ) {
    $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
    $('div'+sectionID).css( 'display', 'block' );
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    if (
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').length &&
        $('div.section').length
    ) {
        $('div.section').css( 'display', 'none' );
        $('ul#verticalNav li a').each(function() {
            $(this).click(function() {
                showSection( $(this).attr('href') );
            });
        });
        $('ul#verticalNav li:first-child a').click();
    }

});
```

Comment: Its working in fiddle

Comment: hi code is working, I need to create link like following example: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/x9ypj/thispage.html#section2 is it possible..

Comment: It would be really bad if i answer this after this much good answers on this topic you must refer this link and that's all you get it
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change

Comment: Where are you getting the hash tag?

Comment: <ul id="verticalNav">        <li><a href="#section1">Section I</a></li>        <li><a href="#section2">Section II</a></li>        <li><a href="#section3">Section III</a></li>
    </ul><div id="sections"><div class="section" id="section1">
            <h2>Section I</h2> <p>Some content specific to this section...</p></div><div class="section" id="section2">         <h2>Section II</h2><img src="#" alt="BADGER" /></div><div class="section" id="section3">
            <h2>Section III</h2>
            <img src="#g" alt="SNAKE" />
        </div>
    </div>

Comment: plz could you check my demo link: http://jsfiddle.net/bala2024/x9ypj/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this thread:

[On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Can't take credit for it, but you will find your answer in that thread (also mentioned in the comments).

You have to make a function that checks on every hash change like so:

```
$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  .. work ..
});
```

All credits go to the person in the thread I gave you.

Comment: hi billy, can I use following source for this function.. <script type="text/javascript"> $(function(){
  

  $(window).hashchange( function(){
    var hash = location.hash;
    
        document.title = 'The hash is ' + ( hash.replace( /^#/, '' ) || 'blank' ) + '.';
    
    
    $('#nav a').each(function(){
      var that = $(this);
      that[ that.attr( 'href' ) === hash ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass' ]( 'selected' );
    });
  })
  

  $(window).hashchange();
  
});</script>