# onchange event on window.location.href

Tags: javascript, jquery

I would like to trigger some Javascript function when `window.location.href` link changes. Is it possible?

Something like this:

```
$(window.location.href).on('change', function(){
   doSomething();
});
```

Comment: The change event only fires on some input elements (textarea, select, input)

Comment: I suspect he's asking this because he's changing the url on the fly. I found this question for a similar reason.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You said '*something like*', given the example code you're probably looking for the `onbeforeunload` event handler.

From the [Mozilla docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WindowEventHandlers.onbeforeunload):

```
window.onbeforeunload = function(e) {
  return 'Dialog text here.';
};
```

Comment: notice this won't detect some location events such as [hashchange](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change) or [history manipulation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/824349/modify-the-url-without-reloading-the-page).

Answer (score 15):

The hashchange event occurs when there has been changes to the URL anchor part i.e after the `#`

```
window.addEventListener('hashchange', function() {

    alert("Hash Changed");

});
```

Comment: This is a code-only answer. Code-only answers may be valid, but get automatically flagged as low quality. Please add a short explanation why this code works, or what the error was. -[From review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/17604650)

Answer (score 10):

There's no built-in event that gets triggered on all url changes. let's see why:

`window.addEventListener('hashchange',listener)`

- triggers only when there's a change in hash (#) in URL.

`window.addEventListener('popstate', listener);`

- triggers only when the user clicks the back button and not on `pushState()` or `replaceState()` event. Useless for [SPA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) sites.

`window.onbeforeunload()`

- won't work for [SPA](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/SPA) sites and on hashchange.

So, is there a way?
Yes, using [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver):

```js
let previousUrl = "";

const observer = new MutationObserver(() => {
  if (window.location.href !== previousUrl) {
    console.log(`URL changed from ${previousUrl} to ${window.location.href}`);
    previousUrl = window.location.href;
    // do your thing
  }
});
const config = { subtree: true, childList: true };

// start observing change
observer.observe(document, config);
```