# jQuery detect singlepage navigation

Tags: jquery, events, singlepage

I am accessing a web page and I am trying to write a jQuery script to detect whenever the page loads a new content. The problem is, When the page first loads it throws an on('load') event, but every subsequent navigation seems to be within the page and I cannot figure out how to catch those.

This is what I did. Navigate to the below link. Open up Google Chrome devtools console. Try to add a jQuery event listener as below.

```
$(document).on('click',function(){console.log("click");})
```

This works for all the clicks. I tried the load, reload, change event, but that does not work all the time. How do I catch an event when the user navigates to another "page" (or section) within this demo site.

http://www.emc.com/microsites/vipr-demo/index.htm#/vdc/1/admin/dashboard/admin-dashboard

Answer (score 0):

Since your url gets changed when a different section of the web page gets loaded, you can use hashchange event.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onhashchange and [On - window.location.hash - Change?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change)

Comment: Tried this doesnt seem to work:$(window).on('hashchange', function() {console.log("hasChange");});