# How to trigger a function when the url changes

Tags: javascript

I wrote a script that works on Greasemonkey extension to insert a link to a certain site. The problem is that it works only on the first page of that site. I need a script (Javascript only) that triggers a function when the URL is changed.

I find something related to location.hash but unfortunatelly it doesn't work for me.

```
var last_hash = "";

setInterval(function() {
hash = window.location.hash;

if(last_hash != hash && hash.length != 1) {
    processing();
    }
last_hash = window.location.hash;
}, 250);
```

Any ideas?

Comment: See the answers here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/680785/on-window-location-hash-change - you shouldn't be running this in an interval. browsers can just listen on their own (I should say you shouldn't HAVE to run this in an interval. not saying it is specifically wrong)

Comment: Like this `$(window).on('hashchange', function() {
  //.. work ..
});`.

Comment: @Praveen - right exactly, but with raw js it would be a little more verbose

Comment: @KaiQing No buddy, don't say that. We have to give a lot of like: `window.onhashchange = function () {};`. But yeah, that's easy too!

Comment: Thanks. I will check that.

Comment: @praveen - I bet you're right about that too. It's been a while since I did raw JS for this. For all I know all current browsers are equipped to handle that case (which actually looks LESS verbose)

Comment: This is it. Thanks for help.

Comment: Yup. Sure... Enjoy! `:)`